OpenGL rasterization performance across mandatory internal formats
Note that I'm asking about rasterization performance only. So, for the sake of this question, consider just the performance of rendering an untextured Gouraud-shaded triangle, perhaps with blending enabled, ignoring any other tasks like costs of blitting the result, converting to displayable color depths, rendering into texture, etc... so, I'm asking about just the performance of pure rasterization of primitives.
Starting with OpenGL 3.0, there's a list of required internal formats for which every compliant implementation must support rendering (to give more focus to the question, I'm thinking in FBO render buffers).
Now, I have always kept the expectation that if you want maximum performance, you'd better choose 8bit per component formats. I also remember reading that you should avoid floating point render buffers unless you need floating point.
However, most OpenGL code that I have seen for multipass rendering seems to choose "deep color" (ie: deeper than 8/8/8/8) render buffers, even if it's code from more than 10 years ago, which would seem to indicate that either there's no performance penalty in doing so, or the penalty is negligible.
Does this mean that all current GPUs have color interpolators whose hardware supports natively 32bit per component (ie 32/32/32/32), both integer and floating point? Do you know what was the GPU generation after which the hardware of all GPUs got color interpolators deeper than 8-bit?

I think you got it backwards. Pixel shader usually accepts, operates and outputs colors and other data with (possibly reduced) floating point precision (type of gl_FragColor is vec4). Integer support used to be optional and implementations were allowed to operate on integers by converting them to floating point (per GLSL1.20 spec). So rasterization stage almost exclusively operates with floating point values. While choosing non-float backbuffer formats will only reduce precision of output merge stage (which may or may not be critical) with the single benefit of reducing memory consumption.
